# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' (Serial port communication string to integer error)

Tags: python, database, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to write a code that will print the data I get from Arduino to both the console screen and a database,at the same time i need to convert values into integers for plotting but I'm getting **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''** error when converting string to integer

```
import sqlite3 as sql
from itertools import count
import time
import serial
index = count()

x_value = 0
total_1 = 1000
total_2 = 1000


arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=9800, timeout=.1)
arduino.flushInput()
def read_data():
    time.sleep(1)
    ser_bytes = arduino.readline()
    decoded_bytes = ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8")
    return decoded_bytes

with sql.connect('altitude_database.db') as db:   
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Distances")
    timer = []
    
    k = 0
    l = 0
    
    while True:
        value = read_data()
        value = int(str(value))
        print(value) # printing the value
       
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Distances (Time,Distances)")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Distances (Time,Distances) VALUES(?,?)",(k,value))
        db.commit()
        k = k+1
```

Comment: As the error says, you're attempting to parse an empty string as an integer. If you can avoid receiving empty strings, you'll need to check for them before attempting to parse.

Comment: As a quick aid to debugging I suggest that you print the value of decoded_bytes in your read_data() function. Then you'll see what the data looks like

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. when I try to print the value of decoded_bytes in read_data() function I realized that the first few data is blank I added the solution below

Answer (score 0):

When I try to print the value of decoded_bytes in read_data() function with Andy Knight's suggestion ""https://stackoverflow.com/users/2668284/andy-knight"" I realized that the first few data is blank.I solved the problem by checking if value is empty

```
with sql.connect('altitude_database.db') as db: 
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Distances")
    timer = []
    
    k = 0
    l = 0
    
    while True:
        value = read_data()
        if value:    #####solution of the problem#######
            value = int(str(value))
            print(value) # printing the value
            cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Distances (Time,Distances)")
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO Distances (Time,Distances) VALUES(?,?)",(k,value))
            db.commit()
            k = k+1
```